# Different column posts in tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, layout, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm making a tumblr theme, which is based on 2 columns. In the left column, there are entries which are tagged, in the right one entries without a tag.

So I have a {block:Posts} in every column div, in one the entries with tags are rendered, in the other one everything else. But somehow both columns are filled with entries, no matter of what type they are.

My code looks like this right now:

```
<div class="columns">

        <div class="column1">
            {block:Posts}
                <div class="post">
                    {block:HasTags}
                        <ul class="tags">
                            {block:Tags}
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
                                </li>
                            {/block:Tags}
                        </ul>
                    {/block:HasTags}
                </div>
            {/block:Posts}
        </div>

        <div class="column2">
            {block:Posts}
                {block:Video}
                    <li class="post video">
                        {Video-500}{block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                {/block:Video}
            {/block:Posts}
        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/q0etgkr/EIBmz7s0p/infinitescrolling.js"></script>
```

The problem is, the video entries are filled in both columns, even if the code links on them just in the column2.

Comment: Using multiple `{block:Posts}` is fine. Your missing logic to filter the posts in the loop to ones with a tag and ones without a tag. Hint: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags

Comment: @mikedidthis Could you please check the code I've just added to the post. Really don't get the problem, for me the order seems logic.